# Fastest way to square the result of a subtraction?

Tags: c

I need to square the result of a subtraction, and I need it to be fast.

I have identified some possible approaches, but I would like to hear the pros and cons

```
unsigned int a = 5;
unsigned int b = 7;


/* Approach 1a */
unsigned int c  = (a - b) * (a - b);

/* Approach 1b */
int d = (a - b);
unsigned int e = d * d;


/* Approach 2a */
unsigned int f = abs(a - b) * abs(a - b);

/* Approach 2b */
unsigned int g = abs((a - b) * (a - b));

/* Approach 2c */
unsigned int h = abs(a - b);
unsigned int i = h * h;


/* Approach 3a */
unsigned int j = (a > b) ? ((a - b) * (a - b)) : ((b - a) * (b - a))
```

I am not sure how to ensure random negative numbers that would not be optimized out by the compiler, so I just wrote the general concept. I'm sure it should be possible to single out some solutions as (sub-)optimal by just looking at them.

Comment: What did you see when you profiled them?

Comment: All of these look identical, and I doubt there will be any significant difference.  What research have you done?

Comment: Any decent optimizer will generate the same code for 1a and 1b.

Comment: I don't see any reason to use `abs()` or check for negative numbers. The multiplication instruction speed is not dependent on whether the operands are negative or positive.

Comment: Doubling Barmar's comment. Clang with -O3 produces same assembly for 1a and 1b: https://godbolt.org/z/a9K75WfYK

Comment: @devgirl05 All your approaches are just wrong. The expression ( a - b) can produce a very big unsigned integer value.:) At least in general the expressions should be catsted to long long int as for example ( long long int )a - b

Comment: Approach 4: `a * a + b * b - 2 * a * b;`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Re ”All your approaches are just wrong. The expression ( a - b) can produce a very big unsigned integer value.”: If y > x, `x−y` yields 2^w+(x−y), where w is the width of `unsigned`, and squaring that produces (2^w)^2+2•2^w•(x-y)+(x−y)^2. When that is reduced modulo 2^w, the result is (x−y)^2. Thus, the C code `(x-y)*(x-y)` produces the correct result for (`x`−`y`)^2 if it is representable.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow When getting an unsigned difference from the subtraction of two unsigned values and then squaring the difference, it doesn't matter if the minuend is smaller than the subtrahend or not as long as the absolute difference fits in half the width of the resulting unsigned type. For example, `(uint_least32_t)0xffff * (uint32_least32_t)0xffff` and `-(uint_least32_t)0xffff * -(uint_least32_t)0xffff` evaluate to the same value `0xfffe0001`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Your comment just does not make sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ian's comment makes perfect sense.  It's another way of saying the same thing that Eric said just before him.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow look at an 8-bit example for simplicity: `0xFF * 0xFF = 0xFE01` then modulo `100h` gives the expected `1`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I wrote clearly that in general this does not work correctly.

Comment: I hadn't considered that uints would be overflowing, I somehow thought they would get implicitly turned into an int like in 1b. Would casting be semantically more correct or just introduce a slowdown?  Can you guys give me your favourite alternative?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I did not previously respond to your original comment.  As to what you're saying now, it depends on what you mean by "in general".  If the mathematical result of the OP's overall `(a - b) * (a - b)` is too large to be represented by type `unsigned int` then yes, the stored result will be different from the mathematical one.  But that's not a matter of the details of the expression.  If the mathematical result *is* representable as an `unsigned int` then either the OP's 1a or 1b will reliably produce that result, regardless of there being large integer intermediate results.

Comment: @devgirl05, all arithmetic operations with two operands of type `unsigned int` have results of type `unsigned int`.  Including all subtraction operations.  ***But that is not a problem for you*** and your particular computation.  I see no reason for you to involve `abs()` -- it is conceivably even harmful in this case -- and the ternary expression is both unweildy and unlikely to perform better than 1a and 1b. Supposing that the `unsigned int` is definitely what you want for the result type, my advice would be to go with your favorite between 1a and 1b.

Comment: @devgirl05, what result do you expect if _square of the subtraction_ is not in the `unsigned` range?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I made sure it is, but if it wasn't, I would expect the value would overflow as many times as the type can fit and leave the modulo.
I'm really confused why "negative" unsigned ints are even possible. Don't you introduce an overflow by multiplying (-2) == (maximum possible uint value - 2). (Type gets promoted implicitly I guess, but it's still weird. So the max unsigned int for squaring should be sqrt(UINT_MAX)?)

Comment: @devgirl05 Minor: off-by-1 " (-2) == (maximum possible uint value + 1 - 2)".

Comment: @devgirl05, negative `unsigned int`s are not possible *per se*.  You get the result modulo `UINT_MAX + 1` instead, just as you seem to be expecting.  And if you square that, you get the (in your case) desired result.  If you like, you can view that as a property of modular arithmetic.

Comment: @devgirl05 Given your speed goal and "I made sure it is (in `unsigned` range)", I would expect any result outside the `unsigned` range to be a "Don't care", rather than a modulo one, as it does not happen for your application.  By having it a "Don't care", a faster solution _might_ be possible.

Comment: @devgirl05 Mathematically, the calculation: is (((a - b) mod M) * ((a - b) mod M)) mod M, where M is one more than the maximum value of the unsigned type (e.g. `UINT_MAX+1`. E.g. if M is 256, a is 3, and b is 5, then a - b = 3 - 5 = -2, (a - b) mod M = -2 mod 256 = 254, ((a - b) mod M) * ((a - b) mod M) = 254 * 254 = 64516, (((a - b) mod M) * ((a - b) mod M)) mod M = 64516 mod 256 = 4.

Comment: Approach 1b can involve converting a large `unsigned int` values to `int` when the value cannot be represented by `int`. Technically, the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised. In practice, most implementations just treat the resulting bit pattern as an `int` value without batting an eyelid. But the problem can be avoided altogether by changing `int d` to `unsigned int d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider another option where the difference is saved in an `unsigned` rather than an `int`.

```
// Recommend avoiding
/* Approach 1b */
int d = (a - b);
unsigned int e = d * d;

/* Approach 1b_alt */
unsigned int d_alt = (a - b);
unsigned int e_alt = d_alt * d_alt;
```

- Advantage 1: When `a - b > INT_MAX`, saving the difference as an `int` incurs *implementation defined behavior*.  The typical implementation defined behavior performs as OP's desires, yet that is not guaranteed.
- Advantage 2: When the difference is greater than `sqrt(INT_MAX)`, yet does not exceed `sqrt(UINT_MAX)`, squaring that using `int` math is `int` overflow and *undefined behavior*, but saving as an `unsigned` incurs no overflow (and no UB even if out of range).  The typical undefined behavior of `int` overflow performs as OP's desires, yet that is not guaranteed.  Potential UB should be avoided.

---

Given the modulo nature of `unsigned` math, `/* Approach 1a */` and `/* Approach 1b_alt */` are specified to produce the same result.
I recommend either of these approaches.  They both perform as desired for all `a, b` where `|a-b|^2 <= UINT_MAX`.

---

[OP asserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78042778/fastest-way-to-square-the-result-of-a-subtraction/78044147#comment137586233_78042778) that the final result is in the `unsigned` range, so values of `a, b` that result otherwise are not important to optimize.

Answer (score 6):

As a general rule, you should avoid branches to make a fast program. Therefore, using extra `abs` and conditional operators are not good.

Also do trust your compiler with optimization.

I tested a slightly modified version of your code on [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/), using x86-64 gcc 13.1 with `-O2` option.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int  hoge(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
    /* Approach 1a */
    unsigned int c  = (a - b) * (a - b);

    /* Approach 1b */
    int d = (a - b);
    unsigned int e = d * d;


    /* Approach 2a */
    unsigned int f = abs(a - b) * abs(a - b);

    /* Approach 2b */
    unsigned int g = abs((a - b) * (a - b));

    /* Approach 2c */
    unsigned int h = abs(a - b);
    unsigned int i = h * h;


    /* Approach 3a */
    unsigned int j = (a > b) ? ((a - b) * (a - b)) : ((b - a) * (b - a));

    /* test c, e, f, g, i, j here */
    return c;
}
```

In this setting, unused approaches are optimized out.

Returning `c`, `e`, `f`, and `g` resulted in this identical result:

```
hoge:
        movl    %edi, %eax
        subl    %esi, %eax
        imull   %eax, %eax
        ret
```

Returning `i` resulted in:

```
hoge:
        subl    %esi, %edi
        movl    %edi, %eax
        negl    %eax
        cmovs   %edi, %eax
        imull   %eax, %eax
        ret
```

Returning `j` resulted in:

```
hoge:
        cmpl    %edi, %esi
        jnb     .L2
        movl    %edi, %eax
        subl    %esi, %eax
        imull   %eax, %eax
        ret
.L2:
        movl    %esi, %eax
        subl    %edi, %eax
        imull   %eax, %eax
        ret
```

From this test, we can say Approach 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b should have the same performance, and Approach 2c and 3a will have worse performance than them.

Note that the result should depend on compilers, options, and target machines.

I think Approach 1b is the best of approaches here because it is simple and calculation `a - b` is not manually repeated.

If you want faster operation, your choice may be using SIMD operations or GPU.

Comment: +1. It's fascinating that approach 2c is compiled differently from approach 2a; somehow the compiler can tell that the `abs` is unneeded in approaches 2a and 2b, but not that it's unneeded in approach 2c.

Comment: MikeCAT, note that approach 1b risks undefined behavior (UB).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oops, `d` should be `unsigned int`, not `int`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert, but I think 2c is the best, since it does the job concisely.

As for fast, I have no idea how C optimization works, but I think computing the absolute value of (a-b), then squaring takes less time, since your only performing 3 operations, compared to 5 in 2a and 4 in 2b.

Again, not an expert, just my thoughts.

Comment: Except that computing the absolute value, as 2c does, is not at all necessary here.  Given `a` and `b` having type `unsigned int`, their difference is always well defined and always has type `unsigned int`, which is already positive.  *That poses no problem for the computation*, but converting the difference to `int` to pass it it to `abs()` potentially does.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check it yourself:

Also `x*x` is always non negative (abstacting from complex numbers) so `abs(x*x) == x*x`. The problem is that the multiplication might overflow invoking Undefined Behaviour.

```
unsigned int foo_1a(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    /* Approach 1a */
    return (a - b) * (a - b);
}
unsigned int foo_1b(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    int d = (a - b);
    return d * d;
}
unsigned int foo_2a(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    return abs(a - b) * abs(a - b);
}
unsigned int foo_2b(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    return abs((a - b) * (a - b));
}
unsigned int foo_1c(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    unsigned int h = abs(a - b);
    return h * h;
}
unsigned int foo_3a(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? ((a - b) * (a - b)) : ((b - a) * (b - a));
}
```

and the resulting code:

```
https://godbolt.org/z/q4n7xvasW
```